# header overlapping when minimized

Tags: html, css

When I minimize the window, the div containers are overlapping. Is there a way to avoid this? I tried minimizing the min-width to a reasonable amount but the problem still persist

Image of context:
[image]

Html5  :

```
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <img src="images/logo.png">

                <div class="coloredBG"></div>
                <div class="coloredBG"></div>
                <div class="coloredBG"></div>
                <div class="coloredBG"></div>
    </header>

</body>
```

CSS

```
.header {
    max-width:1200px;
    min-width:200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:30px;
}

.coloredBG {
    background: #406d85;
    height:100px;
    width:170px;
    float:right;
    margin-left:3px;
    -webkit-transition: background 1s;
    -o-transition: background 1s;
    -moz-transition: background 1s;

}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/farhanafzal/RvV6K/)

Comment: Can you provide an image/wireframe of your desired context ? I updated your fiddle to 'see' a little more. http://jsfiddle.net/RvV6K/1/  'still, like user JustAnil, i don't get your point.

Comment: @MilchePatern [link](http://imgur.com/AAHm8T3) I think question is much clearer now. As i minimize the window, the div containers are going down, they are not fixed

Comment: Well your containers are 170px wide and 'float' on right side. If not-enough space is available, it's a normal behavior to 'go' somewhere else. (under)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/z3c6s/)**

- Give your page a minimum width.
- Set overflow to auto
- Float img to left
- Wrap the divs in a container which takes up the remaining width
- Center container by giving divs display:inline-block

### Markup

```
<header class="header">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/380x150">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="coloredBG"> 
                </div>
                <div class="coloredBG">
                </div>
                <div class="coloredBG">
                </div>
                <div class="coloredBG">
                </div>
           </div>
    </header>
```

### CSS

```
body
{
    min-width: 775px;
    overflow:auto;
}
header img {
    border-right:solid #406d85 1px;
    padding-right:20px;
    float:left;
}
.container
{
    text-align: center;
    overlow:auto;
}
.header {
    max-width:1200px;
    min-width:200px;
    margin-top:30px;
}


.coloredBG {
    background: #406d85;
    height:100px;
    width:170px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:3px;
    -webkit-transition: background 1s;
    -o-transition: background 1s;
    -moz-transition: background 1s;

}

.coloredBG:hover {
     background: #103b51;
    -webkit-transition: background 2s;
    -o-transition: background 2s;
    -moz-transition: background 2s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi is this any better? I think it gets around your problem?

I wrapped your boxes in another div and gave that a width.

```
    <header class="header">
    <img src="images/logo.png" />

    <div class="backgrounds">
            <div class="coloredBG"> 
            </div>
            <div class="coloredBG">
            </div>
            <div class="coloredBG">
            </div>
            <div class="coloredBG">
            </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
.backgrounds{
position:relative;
width:700px;
float:right;
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/farhanafzal/RvV6K/